# iOS publish app: Binary refused

Tags: ios, cordova, app-store-connect

I just published my iOS application (Cordova) and the validation team refused it for this reason:

> Guideline 2.5.1 - Performance - Software Requirements
>   We noticed that this app is using an older version of the Crittercism library that accesses non-public data structures in the Objective-C runtime. As a reminder, apps may only use public APIs, and you should phase out any deprecated features, frameworks or technologies.

Does anyone have an idea of what exactly it is?

Comment: are you using cordova-plugin-apteligent?

Comment: no, actually I'm using com.Crittercism.PhoneGap.( the app was developed by another  and I'm fixing some bugs)

Comment: right now, I'm trying to update all plugins using cordova-check-plugins --update=auto

Comment: well, it's really the same plugin, they changed the name from `com.Crittercism.PhoneGap` to `cordova-plugin-apteligent`. As the id is the old one, maybe the `cordova-check-plugins` doesn't work properly, so uninstall `com.Crittercism.PhoneGap` and install `cordova-plugin-apteligent`

Comment: It works. But now, the app is not working. I got many errors and warnings in xcode console.

Comment: if I update plugins, should I rm and add platforms again?

Comment: You can try, but when you update plugins, some things might work, specially when there is a major bump in the version, I wouldn't recommend using something like cordova-check-plugins as it updates automatically and you don't know which plugins where updated or to which version. Even if it's a lot of work, you should do it manually plugin by plugin and reading the plugins README and/or release notes/changelog

Comment: thanks @jcesarmobile, I will do it.

Comment: @jcesarmobile I updated com.Crittercism.PhoneGap to cordova-plugin-apteligent but Apple refused again my binary with same Error message.

Comment: Then the plugin needs an update too, report it on the issues section of the plugin repo

Comment: thanks, I contacted apple support to know more details. I think maybe the problem causes by another plugin.

Comment: I doubt is another plugin, this one has not updated the Crittercism SDK for 3 years https://github.com/crittercism/PhoneGap/blob/master/platforms/ios/CrittercismSDK/libCrittercism_v5_4_1.a

Comment: So I should remove it cause I want to publish my app ASAP.

Comment: @jcesarmobile can I replace it by another plugin? or  if I remove it, would have an impact to my app?

Comment: I don't know any other plugin, that one seems official, but not maintained. You will have to remove any javascript code calling Crittercism API, just do a search of Crittercism in your code and remove everything you find

Comment: well I think is the best idea right now. Thanks @jcesarmobile